# Underline CSS link mobile width

Tags: html, css

I have this css code and it works fine on large desktops. Once i switch to mobile the underline is under the whole element. I would like to have the underline only under the words in sentence. 
Any help to achive this will be welcomed.
Here is the HTML:

```
 a class="underline-link" 
        href="#">Made with Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amed
```

And here is the CSS:

`.underline-link:after {
 background-color: #0982ae
 }
.underline-link:hover {
color: #0982ae
}
.underline-link:after {
content: "";
height: 1px;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
transform: translateY(1px);
transition: all .15s cubic-bezier(.39, .575, .565, 1);
transition-property: opacity, transform;
width: 100%
}
.underline-link:focus {
outline: none
}


.underline-link {
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, segoe ui, avenir next, 
avenir, helvetica neue, helvetica, ubuntu, roboto, noto, arial, sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
text-decoration: underline;
color: #b3b3b3;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
color: #087096;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
text-decoration: none;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
}
.underline-link:hover {
text-decoration: none
}
.underline-link:focus:after, .underline-link:hover:after {
opacity: 1;
transition-delay: .2s;
transition-duration: .15s;
transform: translateY(-3px) translateZ(0)
}`

Live preview:[On Codepen](https://codepen.io/alexgrecu/pen/LdMwJb)

Comment: i tried it right now and i've only had to delete  the first text-decoration: none; declaration to see the underline property acting as expected. You must check inheritance inspecting which properties are the browser rendering and with which values and from where they come. The issue, if there's some (have you cleared cache?) may be in another piece of your code.

Comment: I just updated the comment and if you follow the link and narrow the window you will figure it out what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the issue, it's about position: absolute;
you can check the line position if you change bottom: 0; to top: 0;
i've to think how to trick over it and if there's some way to solve it, at the moment i don't have any solution on mind.

```css
h2 > a {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
    line-height:50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 > a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
h2 > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;

  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
h2 > a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
h2 > a >span {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 > a >span:hover {
  color: #000;
}
h2 > a > span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  top: 40;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
h2 > a > span:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<h2><a><span>Look at this large truncated text effect with css, it's magic! </span></a></h2>
```

i tried with adding a span and setting the same but on top but i can't get rid on how moove this line, it keeps up due to display and positions so... i think this, as you thinked, can't work, sorry.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. The thing is that if you make the sentence longer and narrow under 400px [the screen width] the only underline words are the last ones. I would like to have the whole sentence undeline [only] no matter the screen size.